# Push a file to Github/Gitlab without adding it to .git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a bunch of large files which never change and they end up occupying a ton of space in `.git`.

Is it possible to `git add` and `git commit` files (such that you can `git push` them) without them being added to `.git`?

Answer (score 2):

(in this problem if you don't want to push it to Github you can just gitignore your files in .gitignore)

create your .gitignore file in your project

```
touch .gitignore
```

then add files you want to .gitignore by writing it, example:

```
example.mp4
```

or

```
*.mp4
```

But if you want to push it to github you can use git LFS (Large File Storage)

Download and install git lfs:

```
git lfs install
```

now you can select the file types you'd like Git LFS to manage:

```
git lfs track "*.psd"
```

if your file mp4 then you can do this:

```
git lfs track "*.mp4"
```

or for specific file:

```
git lfs track "example.mp4"
```

now make sure .gitattributes is tracked:

```
git add .gitattributes
```

last step. Just commit and push to Github as you normally would, good luck.
for more details -> https://git-lfs.github.com/

hope this helps :)

Comment: I followed the `git lfs` instructions, but when you do `git add .` the files still are added to `.git`. And when you use `.gitignore`, the files don't get pushed

Answer (score 0):

As Acla Putra said, the clever idea is to create a `.gitignore` file.
I also suggest you this way.

On the other hand, `git add` is the tool used to select what you want to track for your next commit.
If you want to track **all** your files you can use `git add .` or, on the othen hand, if you want to decide what you want to track you can use `git add file1.c`, `git add file2.txt` etc...

Look at [Git add description](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Comment: Does `.gitignore` still work if you want to **push** the files?

Comment: What do you mean? The `.gitignore` must be added to you commits. However I think you should firstly untrack the files you don't want, then you put the in the `.gitignore` and after that you run `git add .`. The files you want to exclude now shouldn't be added.

Comment: I want to **push** **all** files. I just don't want them to be added to `.git`

Comment: If you push all the files, then they will be added automatically inside `.git`. If they aren't present inside the `.git` it means that you are not tracking them, then you can't push them. Git is a tool made for tracking files, if you track them you can save them, conversely you aren't saving them.